# Converting Vector into List

Tags: r, list, vector

I would like to convert the vector

`par<-c(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 1.8, 1.5)`

into a list that has three elements and each element is made of two values from the par vector. In essence, the List is supposed to look like

```
 $X1
 [1] 0.5 0.7

 $X2
 [1] 0.9 1.0

 $X3
 [1] 1.8 1.5
```

This

`as.list(data.frame(matrix(par, ncol=3, byrow=FALSE)))`

is the only way I have come up with but there has to be a better way!

Comment: So do you want a `list` or a `matrix`? I'm really not sure.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Not sure it's any better, but maybe: `split(par, rep(1:3,each=2) )` ?

Comment: something appropriate with `split` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` is probably the most appropriate function for this sort of task:

```
split(par, rep(1:3,each=2) )

#$`1`
#[1] 0.5 0.7
#
#$`2`
#[1] 0.9 1.0
#
#$`3`
#[1] 1.8 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x <-c(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 1.8, 1.5)
lapply(1:(length(x)/2), function(i) x[i:(i+1)])
```